# Azure Service Tag for Dynamics365

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm

I want to secure a CosmosDB with a VNET integration. Several services should get access to that. I would like to solve that via Service Tags on the NSG of the subnet.

But I have one issue: a custom data provider in Dynamics365 needs access to that database as well. But there is no Service Tag "Dynamics365" in Azure Service Tags. It is only "Dynamics365ForMarketingEmail". And when I try to get the Dynamics365 IP address ranges, the documentation simply states "Azure IPs" - so basicall **all** Azure IPs.

Does somebody have a tipp on how to solve this issue?

Comment: I am also in similar situation. Love to know how to secure/filter incoming traffic to Azure service originating for D365.